# Is there a way of handling Page Expired errors in PingFederate?

Tags: single-sign-on, pingfederate

The SSO product PingFederate [produces a "Page Expired" when it cannot find the request in its table of recent requests](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Page-Expired-Error).  They state, in a manner reminiscent of ["640K ought to be enough for anybody."](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2534312/the--640k--quote-won-t-go-away----but-did-gates-really-say-it-.html), that

```
This is unlikely since PingFederate's state table handles up to 10000 requests by default.
```

Well, guess what, this PingFederate server is kind of busy (producing 10MB of logs per minute), so if the user should wait for, say, an hour, 10K requests have been produced and that state table no longer contains the lookup key (of cookie+nonce).

So, apart from trying to keep the user from staying on the logon screen, is there a way I can instruct PF to "redirect user back to logon screen in case of Pag Expired"?

Logout requests has exactly this feature, [through the `InErrorResource` parameter](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/jmn1564002985887.html), so the opposite seems likely to exist.

Answer (score 2):

PingFederate does support an InErrorResource parameter for both the [IdP-init SSO](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/edg1564003024358.html) as well as [SP-init SSO](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/rzt1564002969660.html) endpoints. This being said, I doubt that the InErrorResource value will be kept when the state is dropped, PingFederate might end up with no knowledge of the user and request, resulting in the same error.

If the environment is busy as you stated it would make more sense to adjust the size limits to avoid the state being lost. The documentation explains [here](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/pcl1589386082635.html) how these can be configured, and what each limit controls. It's worth noting that increasing these limits will have an impact on memory usage, handle with care.

Comment: You could also point them to the [persistent authentication sessions](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/pingfederate-101/page/ebn1564002983293.html) stuff, Mehmet.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I guess an alternate way of avoiding being stuck on the logon screen (as would happen in a hybrid app using a web view), would be to customize the page expired template to have a javascript initiated redirect back to the login page?

Comment: I’m not sure persistent sessions would help here since the issue is before a successful authentication, or am I missing something Andy?

Comment: Editing the error template is also an option, however since the state is lost PingFederate might not know where to send the user after authentication, except there’s a single target application which can also be used as a default. I’d still advise sizing the environment properly for your needs.

Comment: @MehmetY. Good point about not knowing where to send them. I did not think about the fact that this template of course is shared among all applications using SSO, so sending them by default back to my own application, would of course not make sense. Regarding your question before that, the authentication itself is successful. Killing the app and reloading it will often land me straight back into an authenticated state, since the auth itself went fine the last time, just not the redirect.